# Why does the US Declaration of Independence use the word "depository" instead of "depositories"?

Tags: grammatical-number

In the following paragraph from the US Declaration of Independence, it seems to me "depository" should be plural.  Is it an error, or is there a reason for it?

> He has called together legislative bodies at places unusual,
>   uncomfortable, and distant from the depository of their public
>   Records, for the sole purpose of fatiguing them into compliance
>   with his measures.

This question is not only about whether it's an error, but also whether there is a reason for it.  All the answers I'm seeing and finding seem to point towards it's being technically correct but not as correct as it could be, but with no explanation of why that word choice was made, other than the implied assumption that it was a semi-error, in the sense that the plural would have been more correct but wasn't strictly required.

But those answers don't really answer it, as they only vaguely assume that answer, while arguing that it was technically correct, which only answers part of the question.

In any case, on the assumption that a complete answer is not really available, I will just assume it was a careless semi-error, not worth correcting because it was technically correct, and because the author did not have a word processor.

I'm also seeing a notice that the question was marked as an exact duplicate while I was typing the above additional paragraphs.  It doesn't say what it was marked as an exact duplicate of, just that it was marked as an exact duplicate.  I will assume the above 3 additional paragraphs clarify the question to make it clear that it's not the exact duplicate of whatever.

Comment: Here context is all.

What possible explanations did you research and what did that research not explain, please?

Answer (score 0):

The historical and institutional context here is of multiple multi-cameral legislative bodies (probably all bicameral in British North America), each of which bodies is served by its own **single** depository, e.g., the Library of Congress serves both the US House of Representatives and the US Senate. So "their" refers to the plurality of legislative bodies whereas "depository" refers to the single depository of each body. I agree with you that it is an awkward construction.